# Firefox 39.0 is not opening while using Selenium Webdriver 2.46.0

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1.Update your Firefox browser to latest version(32.0.2) & use latest version of web driver(2.43.1).
2.Create driver object for Firefox Driver class.
2.Navigate to a web page using the driver object.

What is the expected output?
Webdriver should open the desired page

What do you see instead?
Firefox is  up but &got the following exception:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Joiner$MapJoiner.appendTo(Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

For stack trace,Please refer the attached screen shot:Screen_shot.png

Selenium version:2.46
OS:Windows 7 professional
Browser:Firefox
Browser version:39.0

Comment: Selenium support till firefox 33.0 , Please check here changelogs : https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES

Comment: Ok..but is there no way in which selenium will support Firefox 39.0 by changing code or jar files?

Comment: No.Either use chrome OR use firefox 33.0 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

2.46 supports FF up to the version 38. 39 is not (yet) supported. You need to downgrade browser version.